# Optimización de código en Python "The Hangman game"

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimización

Escribí este código en Python del juego clásico *"The Hangman Game"* o *"El Ahorcado"* el cual toma de un archivo una lista de palabras y aleatoriamente escoge una palabra.

```
import random
import os

def formats():
    os.system("cls")
    print("""      
        ##    ##      ###      ####    ##  #########  ####      ####      ###      ####    ##
        ##    ##     ## ##     ## ##   ##  ##         ## ##    ## ##     ## ##     ## ##   ##
        ########    #######    ##  ##  ##  ##  #####  ##  ##  ##  ##    #######    ##  ##  ## 
        ##    ##   ##     ##   ##   ## ##  ##     ##  ##   ####   ##   ##     ##   ##   ## ##
        ##    ##  ##       ##  ##    ####  #########  ##    ##    ##  ##       ##  ##    ####
                """ )

def comparation(word, palabra):
    word = word+"\n"
    if word==palabra:
        print("HAS GANADO!!! la palabra es: " + palabra)
        return True
    return False
    

def validating(palabra, lista, user_input):
    cont = 0
    for i in palabra:
        if(user_input == i):
            lista.pop(cont)
            lista.insert(cont, user_input)
        cont+=1
    return lista 

def run():
    with open("./files/data.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")as f:
        word_list = [word for word in f]
        palabra = word_list[random.randint(0,9)]
    lista = ["_" for i in range(0,len(palabra)-1)]

    for i in range(0,10):
        formats()
        print("te quedan", 10-(i), " intentos")

        print(" ".join(lista).upper())
        string2 = "".join(lista)

        if comparation(string2, palabra):
                break

        user_input = input("digite una letra: ")
        assert user_input!="", "HAS PERDIDO!!!, no puede estar vacio"  
        if i==9:
            print("te quedaste sin intentos, GAME OVER!!!")
            break

        if len(user_input)==1:
            lista = validating(palabra, lista, user_input)

        elif comparation(user_input, palabra):
                break
        
        else: 
            print("HAS PERDIDO!!!")
            break
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

[el archivo data.txt es una lista de palabras separadas por línea]

Funciones:

- Lee un archivo y lo vuelve una lista
- verifica si una letra (suministrada por el usuario) pertenece a la palabra
- verifica si una palabra (suministrada por el usuario) es igual a la palabra
- limpia la pantalla y muestra el progreso de la partida(Ganado, Perdido, Intentos y Progreso)

El problema es en la utilización de métodos ya que la idea esperada es que el código sea lo mas optimizado y "*Pythonico*" posible, por ende no hay una sola respuesta.

Comment: también sugerencias como buenas practicas o errores que se presenten son aceptadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es mi versión. Elimine la impresión del banner cada vez, para simplificarlo.

Usamos una variable global para definir los parámetros del proceso

```
max_intentos = 10
```

Simplificamos la validación. Se trata simplemente de recorrer dos listas en paralelo comparando.

```
 def validating(palabra, lista, user_input):
    for i in range(len(palabra)):
        if user_input == palabra[i]:
            lista[i] = user_input
    return lista
```

Simplificar elección de la palabra. Leemos la lista completa. Seleccionamos una palabra al azar (sin importar largo de la lista), eliminamos los espacios y la reducimos a mayúsculas.

```
with open("data.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")as f:
    word_list = f.readlines()
    # Elegir una palabra al azar, eliminar los white-spaces y llevar a mayúsculas.
    palabra = word_list[random.randint(0, len(word_list) - 1)].strip().upper()
```

Crear una lista de elementos repetidos. La forma estándar en Python es

```
lista = ["_"] * len(palabra)
```

en lugar de

```
lista = ["_" for i in range(0, len(palabra) - 1)]
```

Usamos un `for` controlando el número de intentos, evitando llevar un contador por separado

```
for intentos in range(max_intentos, 1, -1):
    print(f"te quedan {intentos} intentos")
```

Ingresar, limpiar y reducir a mayúsculas la letra del usuario

```
user_input = input("digite una letra: ").strip().upper()
```

Validar la letra del usuario, revisar si completo la palabra

```
if len(user_input) == 1:
    lista = validating(palabra, lista, user_input)
    print(" ".join(lista))

    if palabra == "".join(lista):
        print(f"HAS GANADO!!! la palabra es: {palabra}")
        break
else:
    print("Ingresa sólo una letra")
```

Finalmente, usamos la claúsula `else` aplicada al `for`. Este código se ejecuta sólo si el `for`terminó de manera "normal"; si salió por `break`, no se ejecuta:

```
else:
    print("te quedaste sin intentos, GAME OVER!!!")
```

**Código**

```
import random

max_intentos = 10

def validating(palabra, lista, user_input):
    for i in range(len(palabra)):
        if user_input == palabra[i]:
            lista[i] = user_input
    return lista


def run():
    print("""      
     ##    ##      ###      ####    ##  #########  ####      ####      ###      ####    ##
     ##    ##     ## ##     ## ##   ##  ##         ## ##    ## ##     ## ##     ## ##   ##
     ########    #######    ##  ##  ##  ##  #####  ##  ##  ##  ##    #######    ##  ##  ## 
     ##    ##   ##     ##   ##   ## ##  ##     ##  ##   ####   ##   ##     ##   ##   ## ##
     ##    ##  ##       ##  ##    ####  #########  ##    ##    ##  ##       ##  ##    ####
             """)

    with open("data.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")as f:
        word_list = f.readlines()
        # Elegir una palabra al azar, eliminar los white-spaces y llevar a mayúsculas.
        palabra = word_list[random.randint(0, len(word_list) - 1)].strip().upper()

        lista = ["_"] * len(palabra)
        # lista = ["_" for i in range(0, len(palabra) - 1)]

    for intentos in range(max_intentos, 1, -1):
        print(f"te quedan {intentos} intentos")

        user_input = input("digite una letra: ").strip().upper()

        if len(user_input) == 1:
            lista = validating(palabra, lista, user_input)
            print(" ".join(lista).upper())
            string2 = "".join(lista)

            if palabra == string2:
                print(f"HAS GANADO!!! la palabra es: {palabra}")
                break
        else:
            print("Ingresa sólo una letra")
    else:
        print("te quedaste sin intentos, GAME OVER!!!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```